# VB.Net - how to trigger an action after checkbox in GridView row is clicked?

Tags: vb.net

My GridView has a checkbox column which I plan to use to update GridView row data to database upon clicking.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" commandargument="<%# container.displayindex  %>" commandbutton="AddLine" 
             onclick="UpdateDB" Wrap="True" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But now I'm doing small scale testing, triggering a textbox to generate a text once a checkbox is ticked.

```
Protected Sub UpdateDB(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal checkbox1 As CheckBox, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim ixrow As Integer = sender.commandargument
    Dim CheckBoxChecked As Boolean = checkbox1.Checked

    If CheckBoxChecked = True Then

        LineID_DB.Text = "Hello"

    End If

End Sub
```

But during testing when I try out the checkbox, I get this error message:

```
'JavaScript runtime error: 'UpdateDB' is undefined
```

What does it mean by `undefined`? What should I add to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Asp.NET `CheckBox` Control doesn’t have a *Server Side* event called `“onclick”`.
There are other *Asp.NE*T Controls that have those events like `Button` which have `“OnClick”` for *Server Side* or  a property `“OnClientClick”` associated to a *Client Side* click (javascript).
In your case the code interpreter are finding for an Javascript event called ‘onclick’ so if you change as follows
`<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="alert('This is javascript');" …….`
You can see that is a *Client Side* event (javascript).

To do what you want to do (presumably by code viewing) you have to use `“OnCheckedChanged”` Event which fires on Server Side and be sure the `Method/Sub` you have wrote have the
same signature compatible with delegate   `CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged`.
As the code below shows:

**Client Side:**

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="alert('This is javascript');"  OnCheckedChanged="UpdateDB" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

**Server Side:**

```
Public Sub UpdateDB(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim CheckBoxChecked As Boolean = CType(sender, CheckBox).Checked

    If CheckBoxChecked = True Then
        Debug.WriteLine("CheckBox1 is checked")
    End If

End Sub
```